# Orientation Lock of UIViewController - Xcode - Swift

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, swift, uiviewcontroller

How do I force my view controller to stay in portrait mode programmatically? I have created a share extension for my iOS app and I need my view to stay in portrait mode all of the time, despite the orientation of the device. The override methods below do not work:

```
override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> Int {
    return Int(UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait.rawValue)
}
override func preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation() -> UIInterfaceOrientation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait
}

override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return false
}
```

Comment: A share extension appears in another app, not yours. Your code has no say in that app's orientation.

Comment: Matt, I understand, but the extension has its own view controller, it should be able to control that right?

Answer (score -1):

You can use this code in `viewWillApear`

```
 let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait.rawValue
    UIDevice.currentDevice().setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
```